# Is there any reliable source that explains the Tsugumi Ohba-Hiroshi Gamo pen name?

Tags: mangaka, death-note, bakuman

It is said in some sites (including [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiroshi_Gam%C5%8D)) that based on some cross-references the Bakuman and Death Note, the author, Tsugumi Ohba, is actually a pen name, and his real name is Hiroshi Gamo, another 50-year-old mangaka that was some kind of one-hit-wonder in the 90's.

I couldn't find any reliable source for verifying this, does someone know if this is true from some source (interviews, press...)?

Answer (score 6):

These are still just rumors and speculation.

The most notable are in Death Note and Bakuman.

In Death Note, the seminar Light goes to is called "Gamo Seminar":

[image: Exhibit One]

In Bakuman, there is reference to a series called Super Hero Legend. Not only is the concept similar, but even the drawings of this are very clear references to the art style of Hiroshi Gamo's 1993 work Tottemo! Luckyman.

[image: Exhibit Two]

Comment: Perhaps Hiroshi Gamo was an inspiration for Ohba, so this was his way of paying homeage.